# Text manipulation in console

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this :

```
2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName: PROBLEM [2018994] bla bla bla bleh bli blu blo [30393](High|Ack: No)
2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) Server Name 2: PROBLEM [2018f34] doo ba di ba doo [32393](High|Ack: Yes)
2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName 3: PROBLEM [9865994] Link is down [30393](High|Ack: No)
```

I'd like to filter this file and get only the error message for each line. 
With the example I gave, the output would be :

```
bla bla bla bleh bli blu blo
doo ba di ba doo
Link is down
```

One important thing : the server name can sometimes have spaces.
I've tried for hours sed, awk, grep, cut, it's making me crazy. Any clue ?

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Could your inner text itself contain strings such as `2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName 3: PROBLEM [9865994] ` and `[30393](High|Ack: No)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***awk*** solution (for static input format):

```
awk -F'[][]' '{ print $3 }' file
```

The output:

```
 bla bla bla bleh bli blu blo 
 doo ba di ba doo 
 Link is down
```

---

- `-F'[][]'` - considering `[` and `]` as field separators

Comment: What if your text has `[` or `]` in it?

Comment: @Tom, read my 1st sentence: *for static input format*. If the OP would say  "yes, it may contain that" - I'll make the update

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer and explanation, it works great ! Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Perl for dynamic content, assuming format is always the same

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /]\K.*(?=\[)/' file
```

Input

```
2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName: PROBLEM [2018994] bla bla bla bleh bli blu blo [30393](High|Ack: No)
2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) Server Name 2: PROBLEM [2018f34] doo ba di ba doo [32393](High|Ack: Yes)
2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName 3: PROBLEM [9865994] Link is down [30393](High|Ack: No)
2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName 3: PROBLEM [9865994] 2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName 3: PROBLEM [9865994] Link is down [30393](High|Ack: No) [30393](High|Ack: No)
```

Output

```
 bla bla bla bleh bli blu blo
 doo ba di ba doo
 Link is down
 2017-02-28 18:58:00 (UTC) ServerName 3: PROBLEM [9865994] Link is down [30393](High|Ack: No)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/[^]]*.\(.*\)\[.*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
sed -E 's/^.*\[[[:alnum:]]*\][[:blank:]]*(.*)[[:blank:]]*\[[[:alnum:]]*\].*$/\1/' filename
bla bla bla bleh bli blu blo 
doo ba di ba doo 
Link is down
```